# mysqldump version Error while exporting data from MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am getting an error while exporting data from `mysql 5.5.29(winx-64)`. I am using `mysql workbench -gpl-5.2.45(win 32)`.

The error message is:

```
**WARNING**

Error checking mysqldump version
Error retrieving version from mysqldump.exe:
(exit 1)
```

I am new in MySQL.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 14):

Check File->Edit->Preferences, Administrator tab. You need to provide correct path to mysqldump there, or leave field clear to use mysqldump.exe shipped with Workbench.

Comment: Clearing the path solved my problem, too. I'm using MySQL 5.6 and Workbench 6.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You have to start MySql Workbench as Admin. Rightclick on the Icon and select "run as adminstrator" that fix the issue. If this won't fix it have a look at Help > Show log file

Best,
Nils

Answer (score 5):

[image: mysqldump version fix]

"wb_admin_export.py" looks at PATH variable to find mysqldump and get version number....