# Error Checking MySQLDump Version MySQLWorkbench

Tags: mysql-workbench, mysql

I'm trying to export data from mysql using mysqlworkbench. I get the following error.

> Error checking mysqldumpversion Error retrieving version from
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe: exit(1)

I set correct directory for mysqldump.exe in the edit preferences for mysqldump tool and mysql but still i'm getting this error. I'm using **MySQL 5.6** and **Workbench 6.2** .

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqldump version Error while exporting data from mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995059/mysqldump-version-error-while-exporting-data-from-mysql)

Comment: Clearing the path in the settings should be enough to have WB find the exe automatically. Setting the full path there should really solve any issues if the first solution doesn't work for some reason. Also look in the log file (via Help menu) if you can find any indicator for a problem.

Answer (score 1):

On windows you should start Mysql Workbench with Adminrights. In order to do so make a rightclick on the shortcut and select "Execute as admin". This fix the problem for me.

@Mike - Thanks for the hint with the help menu thats help me to find the problem