# how to fix export mysql dump version error

Tags: mysql-workbench

i'm newbies of mysql workbench.
 **i'm having this error when im trying
 to export data,**

> ( ERROR CHECKING MYSQLDUMP VERSION. error retrieving version
>   mysqldump.exe (exit 1)).

I already try to run administrator. and clearing the path in edit preference. but it doesnt work. please can you help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqldump version Error while exporting data from mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995059/mysqldump-version-error-while-exporting-data-from-mysql)

Comment: how to identify duplicate version?

Comment: Looks like you haven't given MySQL Workbench the correct path to your mysqldump.exe.